# Trigger a Jupyter notebook (x) to run from another one (y) but keep the output into x notebook in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have 2 notebooks: *x.ipynb* and *y.ipynb*. I want to ask if there is a way to run a Jupyter notebook from another one with **Python 3**. I know that if i will insert into *y.ipynb* the magic command `%run x.ipynb` i can have the run and also i will have the output of the *x.ipynb*. But i don't need this. I want just to trigger *x.ipynb* to run with a command from *y.ipynb* **and then open *x.ipynb* to see the outputs.**

I also checked the approach to run the notebook through cmd with the command `jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute --inplace x.ipynb` so i can call this command with subprocess maybe into *y.ipynb* but again with this way i cannot see the output into *x.ipynb*.